# Why Missing record warning appear on popup window in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo

I have two views. One form view and 2nd one is a wizard. i am having problem that model constraints applying on both view where i needed to apply on form view. Form view having a button which opens a new view (wizard) with some drop down options to save.

why Missing Record error occurring ?

Views showing following warning messages ..

1 ..."One of the records you are trying to modify has already been deleted (Document type: Registration management). " Appear on popup window

Let me explain scenario,I have top 2 menus and models 1 . Students 2. Registrations ... When i need to register a student via 'Registration' menu its done normally. Registration form view containing a pop up wizard to register with status 'New'.Problem occur, when this procedure starts from Students form view (containing a button to open Registration form view) and Registration form view open a new pop up (window) wizard which changes student status from 'New' to 'Register or something else'.Here i am facing warning message 'Missing Records ...One of the records you are trying to modify has already been deleted (Document type: Registration management).'

here is the code applying constraints on records to check

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('status', 'student_id')
def _checkstatus(self):
    # retrieve students in the current records
    id_check = self.mapped('patient_id')
    exist = self.search([('student_id','in',id_check.ids),('id','not in',self.ids),('status', '=', 'open')])
    if exist:
        raise ValidationError(_('You can not create new registration until student out !' ))
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242383/why-missing-records-warning-message-appearing-in-odoo-10).

Comment: what kind of duplicate?can you explain please?i have a model 'Registrations' and Wizard 'Registrations wizard' and both containing same field 'register_to'. Is this duplication you meant?According to scenario, i need to update student's status.e.g, i have screen of all students list where i need to chose one student form view with button( change status). From that view after clicking open a new popup Window(wizard) which shows some student setting status to apply.On this wizard i need to save changes to apply on 'registration'module.

Comment: They mean it is a duplicate of the other question you asked. The best approach is to update your existing question instead of creating a new question.